# DataGridView show columns in wrong order

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to show my `DataTable` in a `DataGridView` but the issue is that all columns are set in the right order instead of one, even by setting the ordinal to each column in `DataTable` and loading it as `DataSource` the column "Descrizione" is set as 2nd column while it have to be 3rd one.

So the order must be 'Cod Articolo' 'Descrizione' but DataGridView shows it as 'Descrizione' 'Cod Articolo'

Here is a part of method where i setOrdinal and load `DataTable` as `DataSource`

```
    dt.Columns("CheckBox").SetOrdinal(0)
    dt.Columns("Cod Articolo").SetOrdinal(1)
    dt.Columns("Descrizione").SetOrdinal(2)
    dt.Columns("Prezzo Acq old").SetOrdinal(3)
    dt.Columns("Prezzo Acq").SetOrdinal(4)
    dt.Columns("Differ Acq").SetOrdinal(5)
    dt.Columns("Prezzo vend").SetOrdinal(6)
    dt.Columns("Prezzo vend old").SetOrdinal(7)
    dt.Columns("Differ vend").SetOrdinal(8)
    dt.Columns("Prezzo Manuale").SetOrdinal(9)
    MetroGrid1.DataSource = dt
```

[image]

While here is how it comes in `DataGridView`

[image]

After loading data as DataSource i don't do any other actions with the two columns.

Comment: That looks like a MetroGrid.  We probably need a little bit more code.  Where is this code running?

Comment: @LarsTech yes i'm using MetroFramework and this code is executed after a button is pressed. Anyway i just solved by setting DisplayIndex to MetroGrid instead of setting ordinal to DataTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you show your complete code so we getting good solution
i prefer to change this propriety through designer from data grid view or using "code behind" also from data grid view propriety 
sample

first should set data source then change what you wont throuth data grid view

```
    MetroGrid1.DataSource = dt
    MetroGrid1.Columns("CheckBox").DisplayIndex = 0
    MetroGrid1.Columns("Cod Articolo").DisplayIndex = 1
    MetroGrid1.Columns("Descrizione").DisplayIndex 2=
    MetroGrid1.Columns("Prezzo Acq old").DisplayIndex =3
```

Comment: yeah that was it